# find out parent id of a button in android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-button

In my application i hava a linearlayout and its child button. After touch listener on button i need to know id of linearlayout. Here is my code

```
private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener 
{   

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
    {               
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            View v = ((View)view.getParent());
            int id = v.getId();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

i get android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException. how can i get id of linearlayout. Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
View v = ((View)view.getParent());
int id = v.getId();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(id), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This will toast the ID of your linear layout in the integer format that its stored in in `R.java`.

Your current implementation is such that your `Toast.makeText()` matches the [makeText(Context, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29) method signature, which is meant to be used with `R.string.*` elements. However, since you pass it an `R.id.*` element where it expects a string identifier, is uses that to try and find a matching String in strings.xml. When it fails to find one, it throws a `Resources$NotFoundException`.

Comment: now i need to work with the id but can't get integer value of id @Raghav Sood

Comment: Uh, if you're toasting it, then you already have the integer value. Just use the value stored in `id` when you need it

Comment: actually i need to send the value as a integer parameter of a method.just like      View v = ((View)view.getParent());
       int id = v.getId();
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(id), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       boolean canMove = dragButtonFlag(id);

Comment: Erm, so pass it as the parameter? I don't see a problem here.